# Only one view resizes AutoLayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

```
 NSLayoutConstraint *layouts1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_greenView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_grayView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:3.0f constant:0.0f];
[self.view addConstraint:layouts1];
```

Why does only one view resize here?Only the grayView resizes irrespective of the parameter position in the above method?

Comment: Maybe you have ambiguous layouts. The position of the view here does not change the priority of the constraint.

Comment: I have set the constraints from storyboard on both views.Now I want to change the width of any of the 2 views.How do I do it at runtime now.I am using removeConstraint: method to remove widths of both the views (set in storyboard).Then I'm writing the above code.In console it does show some layout issues at runtime.Can you just tell me what am I doing wrong here?I'm just getting started with auto layout programmatically(though I know how to set it through storyboard).

Answer (score 0):

To change the constraints in runtime which you have applied from storyboard, you *don't need to remove it at first place* and then apply a new one with the modified values. All you need to do is change the `constant` property of that constraint.

In your case create two `IBOutlets` for your `width` constraints that you have created via storyboard lets say `greenViewWidthConstraint` and `grayViewWidthConstraint`. Use below mentioned code to make changes to a specific constraint.

```
greenViewWidthConstraitn.constant = <new value>;
```

Now to analyse what could be wrong in your code. As you have not provided much code in your question, but there are few points i would like to hightlight.

1. You mentioned that you removed the `width` constraint for both views and apply the new one which you posted in question. This has only a relationship about the two views width i.e. `greenView.width = 3*grayView.width`. But gray view itself doesn't have any width of its own(unless you have provided some other constraint and not mentioned here). This could lead to a 0 width for both views and can be a reason for conflict with other constraints.
2. You mentioned that there are some layout issues in runtime, which are caused by ambiguous/conflicting constraints and runtime will attempt to render screen by breaking some of them and you may see the views with adjusted frames or the one given in storyboard.

Comment: Thanks .....I already did that.......Can you help me with this one.......I haven't figured it out yet
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33431386/constraints-set-in-code-doesnt-reflect-in-the-outputautolayout-ios?noredirect=1#comment54695905_33431386