# Constraints set in code doesn't reflect in the output(Autolayout iOS)

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have 2 views that I have taken in storyboard but I haven't set any layouts in the storyboard.I want to set them by code.So here is what I did:

I read about autoResizingMask property of a view and 'translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints'.So setting 'translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints' to 'NO' makes sense.So I have done that but still I' not able to set the constraints programmatically.Now,as some constraints are automatically set in storyboard when we take the views from storyboard,I tried:

```
    [self.view removeConstraints:[self.view constraints]];
```

After doing this,it removes all default constraints from the superview(i.e. self.view).But still I am not able to set constraints from code.What should I do?I need some guidance.

Here is my code that I have been using:

```
 [self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
 NSLayoutConstraint *layouts1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_redView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_yellowView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:3.0f constant:100.0f];
[self.view addConstraint:layouts1];
```

Comment: Could you include your code where you set the constraints programatically?

Comment: Ya sure....I will edit my post in a couple of seconds

Comment: You don't need to remove constraints, you just need to setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to NO. But you must add for constraints - width/height/x/y - . See in the console if you have conflicts